# Weird "Cannot Find Symbol" Java, with TreeSet collection

Tags: java, compiler-errors

the code shown below is a java method and part of my code. It is supposed to produce the nth (or xth) prime number. I think I've got it all well, not until the return statement. When I try retrieving the last element in the TreeSet, using the last() method, I receive a "Can't find symbol" error. Need help please.

```
public static int primes(int x)
{

    if (x == 1){return 2;}

    else if (x == 2){return 3;}

    else if(x == 3){return 5;}

    else if(x == 4){return 7;}

    else
    { 

    int hold = 0;

    Set<Integer> arr = new TreeSet<>();

    arr.add(2); arr.add(3); arr.add(5); arr.add(7); hold = 7;

    for (int z = 7; z != Integer.MAX_VALUE; z+=2)
    {

        if (isprime(z)){arr.add(z);}

        if (arr.size() == x){break;}
    }

    return arr.last();

    }
}
```

Note: isprime() is defined and coded elsewhere

[Compiler Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bonrQ.png)

Comment: What's the exact error? What symbol can't it find?

Comment: `Set` doesn't have the `last` method.  It is declared in `TreeSet`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Dont link to screen shots of error messages. Code and messages are text, and should be coming as well formatted text in your question.

Comment: @GhostCat are u serious. Didn't I say my code is supposed to produce the last element of the treeset and is not doing it (desired behaviour), did I not add that my code is supposed to produce the xth prime number. What more detail did I need to provide. It's like sometimes you just have fun criticizing questions.

Comment: I wrote two comments, didn't I. That MCVE thing implies that all information is coming **within** the question. **Linking** to a screen shot is basically a no-go.

Comment: Change `Set<Integer>` to `SortedSet<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be changed as follows:

```
return ((TreeSet) arr).last();
```

This will cast the type of `arr` to a `TreeSet` and invoke the `last()` method and return its value in a single statement